# Carry Information into a new Sheet based on a Check Box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm creating a centralized Google Sheets based spreadsheet in which hospital patients' daily treatments are being monitored each day. Each patient has a check box at the end of their row of information that indicates if they have been discharged that day. Since the treatments need to be organized by day, I would like to carry over the non-discharged patients to a new sheet of the same template at the end of each day. AppsScript is a new system for me, so I am asking advice for how best to achieve this.

I have begun looking into AppsScript but I would like to get this functionality working quickly and avoid having to teach myself the whole process before I can.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.